# Wrong converting between int and char and back in C#

Tags: c#, char, int, xor

probably mine is a silly question, but I'm having troubles converting a char value into an int and convert back.

The problem is that I'm trying to decrypt a char value retrieved by an Access DB.

Here is my code

```
char chrVal = 'M';
int intVal = (int)chrVal; // Output 77 'M'
// Now trying to encrypt using XOR
int encIntVal = intVal ^ 203; // Output 134 '†'
// Convert back
char correct = (char)(encIntVal ^ 203); // Output 'M' - CORRECT
char wrong = (char)('†' ^ 203); // Output WRONG value
```

The fact is that when I use the int resulting value from the encrypt XOR, I get correct result ('M'). Instead, when I use the char result from the encrypt XOR (that is what I have in the DB), I get wrong result (unreadable character).

I tried to use different encodings but I can't figure out where is the problem.

Any suggestion?

UPDATE

I found that probably the problem is with ADO.NET OleDbDataReader, because (int)Convert.ToChar(dr["Sex"]) gives me 8224 instead of 134, but I can't find a solution yet.

SOLVED

The character '†' is in the Windows 1252 code page. So I get a byte[] with the correct encoding.

```
byte[] byteVal = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(dr["Sex"])
char correct = (char)(byteVal[0] ^ 203); // Output 'M'
```

Thanks

Comment: this is not cryptography

Comment: @Jodrell - It most certainly is, it's just a caesar shift.

Comment: @Jodrell - I do not need strong cryptography, I only need to decrypt that value from DB.

Comment: @Flea777, on the up side, it will be fast. You essentially have it right already. `chrVal == correct` so you know it roundtrips, just ignore how the `byte` `134` is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

'†' character can be front character for not one but many Unicode values.

I can create a font where 'A' will not be just for 65 ASCII value but any value or i can create a font where all character are 'A'.

Like in your case '†' can be 134 as you say and 8224 as Oded mentioned.

`Give more emphasis on ASCII/Unicode values and not on what that value when converted to character looks like.`

Comment: I'm not giving emphasis on what I see, the problem is that also what "the code" sees is wrong. Reading from database with Convert.ToChar(dr["Sex"]) gives that 8824 char.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `'†'` is 8224, not 134. (@Oded mentioned this first)  You can use `'\u0086'` instead, which is 134.

Comment: Yes, the problem is exactly that. However, (char)('M' ^ 203) returns '†' but (char)('†' ^ 203) DOES NOT returns 'M'

Comment: In the font you're using, 134 (apparently) looks like 8224, but the `'†'` in your code is 8224, not 134.  If you use `(char)('\u0086' ^ 203)` (0x86 == 134) instead, the result is the expected 'M'.

Comment: I'm reading that value from a database with a DataReader. Using Convert.ToChar(dr["sex"]) I obtain 8224.